# project.assets.json targeting net6.0 vs net 60, causes error in ASP.NET code generator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, command-line-interface, code-generation

Getting the following error when trying to run the ASP.NET code generator from the CLI:

> Error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net60'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net60' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.

The `project.assets.json` includes a target for `net6.0` vs `net60`. I imagine I either added the period or failed to add it somewhere, and now am getting this?

Running `dotnet restore` is successful. Running `dotnet build` is successful. The error only shows up when attempting to run the code generator:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name ProductsController 
       -m Product --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout
       --referenceScriptLibraries -dc MvcProtoDbContext
```

Comment: Disappointed that nobody else has figured this out. I haven't tried to scaffold a controller in ages -- though I was sure I _had_ done it with dotnet since moving from Visual Studio to VS Code.

`net6.0` **is** the correct target (otherwise your build wouldn't have worked!)

Comment: I tried changing `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net60</TargetFrameworks>` and got the fascinating error message `Duplicate frameworks found: 'net6.0, net6.0'. ` So, apparently it thinks they're the same, so I changed back to a single `<TargetFramework>net60</TargetFramework>` and got rid of _this_ error, but I can't say that's the real answer, as now it errors with `Scaffolding failed.
Add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project as a NuGet package reference.`, though that is absolutely in the .csproj

Comment: On https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#latest-versions `net6.0` is listed as the only value, and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/1182) github issue mentions "net60 appears to be an alias for net6.0".